# Using clearTimeout to cancel a timeout event

Tags: javascript, prototypejs, dom-events

I have the following code but the clear timeout doesn't work and I can't understand why, does anyone have any ideas? (Using the Prototype framework)

```
function foo() {
    $("navigation").observe('mouseover',
        function (event) {
            clearTimeout(bar);
        }
    ).observe('mouseout',
        function (event) {
            setTimeout(bar, 1000);
        }
    );
}

function bar() {
    alert("hi");
}
```

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You need to store the result of `setTimeout` in a variable, and use `clearTimeout` to clear that variable, not the function:

```
var timer;

function foo() {
    $("navigation").observe('mouseover',
        function (event) {
                clearTimeout(timer);
        }
    ).observe('mouseout',
        function (event) {
                timer = setTimeout(bar, 1000);
        }
    );
}

function bar() {
    alert("hi");
}
```

Comment: Hey, no problem. Be sure to mark the answer solved by choosing one of the answers as the "accepted" solution.

Comment: I actually had a problem when the timer variable was not global. I had to use window.timer; I suggest you expand on your answer.

Answer (score 6):

Because the `clearTimeout` function take the argument **returned** by the `setTimeout` function:

```
var t = null;
function foo() {
    $("navigation").observe('mouseover',
        function (event) {
            if (t != null) clearTimeout(t);
        }
    ).observe('mouseout',
        function (event) {
            t = setTimeout(bar, 1000);
        }
    );
}

function bar() {
    alert("hi");
}
```

Answer (score 4):

See the mozilla docs on [window.setTimeout()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.setTimeout):

setTimeout actually returns a reference which you can use to [clear the timeout](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.clearTimeout#Example):

```
tId = setTimeout(bar, 1000);
clearTimeout(tId);
```