# Removing a jquery plugin

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins

After I've called a jquery method that is part of a plugin, I want to terminate what it is doing. The plugin has an internal function that continously gets called with setTimeout. When my html content no longer needs this plugin, I want to stop the plugin otherwise its internal function goes on indefinitely. I thought that maybe I can either remove the plugin from the element that it is attached to or call clearInterval on the internal timer but I'm not sure how to access that from the object the plugin is attached to.

Comment: we need to see the plugin

Comment: Does the plugin not have some sort of documentation?

Comment: Found a duplicate here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/8302569/753632

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `clearTimeout()` method to clear your `setTimeout()`.

More info [here](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_cleartimeout.asp) and  [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1893533/using-cleartimeout-to-cancel-a-timeout-event).

Comment: I think the OP knows that (though the question mentions `clearInterval()` rather than `clearTimeout()`). Isn't the main point that he or she doesn't know how to access the internals of the plugin to get the timer id to pass to `clearTimeout()`?

Comment: He must use the `clearTimeout()`  instead of `clearInterval()`. That's the only answer that I can do without more info about the plugin.